# Can anyone give a better explanation of Authorization and Authentication of Django tasty pie?

Tags: django, tastypie

I am sort of stuck while creating something very simple - a new user.

Workflow in my head is this: User sents query with the api key. Checks if the user exists or not. if not, create the user.

This is my UserSignUpResource:

```
   class UserSignUpResource(ModelResource):

        class Meta:
            object_class = User
            queryset = User.objects.all()
            allowed_methods = ['post']
            include_resource_uri = False
            resource_name = 'newuser'
            excludes = ['is_active','is_staff','is_superuser']
            authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
            authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
            models.signals.post_save.connect(create_api_key, sender=User)

        def obj_create(self,bundle,request=None,**kwargs):
            try:
                bundle = super(UserSignUpResource, self).obj_create(bundle,request,**kwargs)
                bundle.obj.set_password(bundle.data.get('password'))
                bundle.obj.save()
            except IntegrityError:
                raise BadRequest('The username already exists')
            return bundle
    def apply_authorization_limits(self,request,object_list):
        return object_list.filter(id=request.user.id,is_superuser=True)
```

My api call:

```
curl -v -X POST -d '{"username" : "puck", "password" : "123456"}' -H "Authorization: ApiKey puck:link" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/newuser/
```

I get a 401 error. That is precisely because I don't know how to create an API key so that I can use it to create new users.

I can see a api column in django admin but it allows me to only create one api key per user. 
Thus, how does that work? How do I make it work?

Very little information on the tutorials. Hardly any blogs about it. Any help would be nice. I am struggling quite bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create ApiKey with:

```
ApiKey.objects.create(user=user)
```

(you can do it through admin interface as well, but be careful that saving empty inline won't actually save it, ie: change date/time field of api key inline).

After you have api_key, this should work:

```
curl -v -X POST -d '{"username" : "puck", "password" : "123456"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/newuser/?username=user&api_key=API_KEY
```

Comment: But isn't this:models.signals.post_save.connect(create_api_key, sender=User) acting like a signal to create an api key?

Comment: Depending of tastypie version you are using, signal is automatically registered or not. See this changeset: https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/commit/966922cb0bd6268895a51ea5e4438e141101bb76

Comment: I finally got through. Did some changes to my own authentication and made it happen. A few more doubts if I may: 1. To make the api a little better, I don't want to send headers with it for every call. Is that possible? 2. Using the same obj_create how do I make it work for logging in a user?

Comment: There is a session authentication shipped with tastypie but I do not have any experience with it.

Comment: Yeah, I've already read the documentation inside out. I really wish there was a working example of a proper implementation. My code is very hacky. The API very insecure.

Comment: @Puck - you can move validation out of obj_create method (see: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validation.html). 

Also, check http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#creating-per-user-resources in documentation. 

But, why are you creating users through webservice.